# Get the three last Matrix blocks

Tags: templating, matrix

I would like to include a file on every block but the last three. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of a for-loop you have access to some [special variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
    {% set isEndBlock = loop.revindex <= 3 %}

    {% if not isEndBlock %}
        {# do things #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another approach would be to change / override the default criteria of the Matrix field’s ElementCriteriaModel.

```
{% set blocksCount = entry.myMatrixField.count() %}
{% set isValid = blocksCount - 3 > 0 %}

{% set startBlocks = isValid ? entry.myMatrixField({
    limit: blocksCount - 3,
}) : null %}
```

Or criteria to get the last 3 blocks:

```
{% set endBlocks = entry.myMatrixField({
    order: 'matrixblocks.sortOrder desc',
    limit: 3,
}) %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch all elements and slice the last 3 elements from them

```
{% set entriesList = entry.fieldHandle.find() %}
{% set start = entriesList|length - 3 %}
{% set end = entriesList|length %}
{% set lastThree = entriesList | slice(start, end) %}
```

Of course you need to make sure you have at least 3 objects your array